# The select funtion show double duplicate data

Tags: php, foreach, drop-down-menu

I have a problem in the select function, why the select data show me double duplicate data?  Hope someone can guide me which part I am getting wrong. Thanks.

Below is my coding:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="jabatan_yang_akses" name="jabatan_yang_akses" title="jabatan_yang_akses" multiple="multiple" style="display:none;">
          <!--<option value="0">Sila Pilih</option>-->
          <?php
          $sql_branch = 'select * from singkatan_jabatan';
          $arr_branch = db_conn_select($sql_branch);
          foreach ($arr_branch as $rs_branch) {
                        foreach ($jabatan_yang_akses_selected as $select_jabatan){
                            if ($select_jabatan == $rs_branch['id']) {
                                $selected = 'selected';
                            } else {
                                $selected = '';
                            }
                            echo '<option value="' . $rs_branch['id'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $rs_branch['singkatan_nama'] . '</option>';
                        }
          }
          ?>
</select>
```

The output is show me like below the picture:

[image: output 1]

Actually I want the output like below the picture:

[image: Output 2]

I am not sure whether I am using foreach twice time then will show me duplicate data in the select box.

updated:

[image: output5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you select all of the options and then loop over the selected ones and output each of the options out for all possible selected items (in this case there are 2 selected items).  If you had 4 selected items, each option will be output 4 times.

You can just check if the option id is in the list of selected items using `in_array()`...

```
      foreach ($arr_branch as $rs_branch) {
          if ( in_array($rs_branch['id'], $jabatan_yang_akses_selected) ) {
              $selected = 'selected';
          } else {
              $selected = '';
          }
          echo '<option value="' . $rs_branch['id'] . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $rs_branch['singkatan_nama'] . '</option>';
      }
```

Comment: Thanks your answer my question. Your answer now is cleared the duplicate data, but no show what I am selected the data. You can view my update above.

Comment: I think in my code I was using the wrong field, I've updated the line `in_array($rs_branch['id'], $jabatan_yang_akses_selected)`, please check that.